# Question closed as too broad although it has a simple answer

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887514/code-for-gaussian-random-field-for-c) just now. I don't understand how it is "too broad", which was the given close reason. The OP posted their example code, and asked how to get it to work without c++11. The answer (given in the comments) was to use a specific header in the Boost c++ library instead. Problem solved. Definitely not too broad.

Comment: Possibly because a non-library answer would require extensive code. Without knowing about that library, I could understand a "too broad" definition. And at that point; its basically asking for off-site resources.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET ok, I buy that, but I am pretty sure there is was also a question on the site at one point(Although maybe it was on mathematics SE) about how to implement gaussian distributed random numbers by hand. It isn't actually as hard as it might sound.

Comment: Unfortunately, close voters don't necessarily know the answer, so it just has to *sound* too broad; which that question certainly does.

Comment: just as sidenote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19944164/1699210) looks like the disputed question.

Comment: @TimSeguine the existence of a similar question doesn't necessarily make a question any more or less valid.

Comment: @bummi Thanks. That piece of information negatively affects my opinion of the question.

Comment: @KevinB the existence of a  strictly broader one on the same topic with upvotes and an answer would seem to though, which was my point. I am almost sure it was on another SE site the more I think about it though, so it isn't relevant anyway.

Comment: It's proven time and time again tho that that isn't the case. Questions fall through the cracks, or may have been considered on topic years ago but aren't now.

Comment: The presence of a previous question on the same topic does not automatically make a new one on that topic appropriate. The guidelines that govern whether a question is appropriate or not are the guidelines that are in effect *at the time the question is asked*. There are many questions here that were on-topic at some point in time that are not now, such as all of the general computer questions that were asked before [su] existed. The site guidelines evolve over time.

Comment: @KenWhite Kevin B already said basically exactly that.

Comment: @TimSeguine: I'm reinforcing it, as it's been said here hundreds of times before. :-) I responded to your post, and expanded on something I thought I could say more clearly.

Comment: Probably because we don't want to encourage "give meh teh codez" questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about everyone else, but when I make a post, I like to have control over whether or not it's a high quality post.

Because of this, I tend to judge the quality of questions from the point of view of someone who does not know the answer.

In the question you linked, It doesn't look like the OP had a library function in mind.  A library function might have solved the issue, but if you're a person who doesn't know the answer, the post looks like it's supplying a requirement, and asking somebody to write code to fulfill that requirement.

He did include an attempt, but since he's not telling us how close the attempt was to working, or what was wrong with it, the attempt didn't really reduce the scope of the problem.

Comment: Question quality isn't evaluated on the basis of answers that it *might* receive anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure it is; e.g. opinionated, no-repro/typo, etc. +1 to this answer though, of course.

Answer (score 5):

That question is basically asking for a substantial program to be written.  It's "Too Broad" because that work is more than should be required for a SO question.

If the asker wants to know how/why his code doesn't work, he should ask that (and clarify what it's doing wrong).  In general, questions in the format of "How do I do [relatively complex thing], Here is my code that doesn't work" are closed (really should be for Unclear, but Broad is fine also I think) because they aren't giving enough information.  Just providing code and then asking "why doesn't this work" isn't a good question: you need to explain what "doesn't work" means and what it does do.

It's not perfect because there isn't a close reason that's perfect - but it's good enough, and it gets the idea across.  What was't done that should've, is a comment left explaining why the question wasn't good enough and how to improve it.

Comment: Subsatntial code to be written? It is literally changing one include directive and using boost namespaces instead of std.

Comment: If it can be answered by 'use boost' then it's not really a valid question.  I'm assuming he wants to know how to implement it himself.  For my first paragraph I'm ignoring all of the code he provided, because without any explanations it _should_ be ignored.

Comment: That is just moving the goal posts. This is precisely the sort of thing that scares newcomers away.

Comment: @TimSeguine That doesn't make sense to me at all.  What goalposts are moving?  Either he was asking for a library to do something, which is not allowed, or he was asking for how to do it in detail, which is fine, but he needs to provide enough of his own code and explain that code such that it is answerable without it being simply a 'please code this for me' 'here you go' question.